# Singular or Plural?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

I know that in general people say

> How are you?

I find out that people used "are" for showing politeness and respect to the person.

But one of my friend always say

> How is you?

so, can I ask "How is you?" for not showing respect and politeness to the person.

Sounds bad, though it is singular question. Should it be "is" or "are"?

Comment: Q: Can I ask, "How is you?" 
A: You can, if you're a [cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CatLolCatExample.jpg).

Comment: ok! Cat is an animal and human is also an animal.

Comment: Good question. There are many some languages like sanskrit, hindi and others where plural form is used out of respect. However this is not the case in english and the is/are usage is simply irregular. You should probably edit your question to remove the assumptions and just make it a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is wrong.

If you look at the verb *to be* [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/to_be.htm), it is *you are* or *he/she/it is*.   In the question form, the wh- is tagged on the front, and the subject and verb swapped around.

Hence:

*How are you?*
*How is she/he/it?*

Note that the *are* has no connection with showing politeness or respect.